# How can I create webScoket server from Android that can communicate with my this JS code that render in my android web view

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

Following code is from my Javascipt (written in Angualr) that code is going to load in the webview of Android application, can anyone suggest that how can we create server that listens my this client-side code

```
let webSocketURL =  "ws://localhost:8080";
webSocket:any;
message = '';
try {
    this.webSocket = new WebSocket(webSocketURL);

    this.webSocket.onopen = (openEvent)=>{
        this.message = "WebSocket OPEN";
            this.webSocket.send('hello from client');
        };
        this.webSocket.onclose =  (closeEvent) =>{
            this.message = "WebSocket CLOSE";
        };
        this.webSocket.onerror = (errorEvent) => {
            this.message = "WebSocket ERROR";
        };
        this.webSocket.onmessage = (messageEvent) =>{
            this.message = "Got message from server is "+ messageEvent;
            console.log('messageEvent',messageEvent);
        };
    } catch (exception) {
        console.error(exception);
        this.message = " Got exception" + exception ;
    }
```

In the HTML page I'm going to print that 'message' variable

```
<h2>Here your message {{message}} </h2>
```